# Android Device doesn't show up in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, macos

Believe me, I know there are a TON of these posts in SO, but I've gone through most of them and have yet to find a solution. Some notes:

1. I'm running Mac OSX Yosemite
2. Both my devices are USB-debug-enabled (rooted HTC One X, and Motorola Moto G)
3. On both devices, I have successfully run the app via Eclipse before (in fact the HTC is my main testing device)
4. My usual method when the device fails to appear is to quit Eclipse, then run `adb kill-server` `killall adb` and then restart Eclipse.
5. This time that method didn't work. I've also tried restarting the phones, and restarting Eclipse multiple times.
6. Running `adb devices` shows the device there (the device's ID, and 'device')
7. I've checked the SDK Manager, just in case there were some magic Mac drivers that I could use. Nope, so such luck.

Anyone got any ideas for this?

Comment: Does your phone's Android version fall above the minSdkVersion version?

Comment: @akodiakson yes it does. The minimum set is 14. My devices are running 4.2.2 and 4.4, which equate to SDK versions 17 and 19. Also, more importantly, these are devices with which I have been debugging this app up to yesterday, and no changes have been made ot the app since then.

Comment: I can't know specifically. Some times I am dumb enough to not notice my phones aren't plugged in. You shouldn't really need drivers on a Mac. When you plug your phone(s) in, can you browse them in Finder?

Comment: @akodiakson O_o okay I don't know what sorcery you possess. It WAS plugged in, that wasn't the issue. But I went into Finder, browsed inside it, then tried it again on Eclipse, and this time it was fine. SORCERY!

Comment: Haha, that's awesome.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Man, you guys are *good*. The device magically started working again.

If anyone else wants to try and reproduce the solution:

1. Attempt to debug on device for about an hour with no success.
2. Consider selling soul. Check craigslist for soul buyers.
3. Post issue on SO.
4. Play several rounds of Zuma. Plug in and out the device each time. Quit Eclipse each time.
5. Swear profusely as you see `adb devices` showing your device just fine, and even the friggin Logcat in Eclipse itself showing the device tittering away, but you just can't *use* the device.
6. Consider changing careers.
7. Call it a night.
8. Open Finder, poke through folder on phone (in my case it just had HTC's software installer).
9. Try again, because you hate yourself.
10. It works now.